# Merging PDFs while retaining custom page numbers (aka pagelabels) and bookmarks

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfrw

I'm trying to automate merging several PDF files and have two requirements: a) existing bookmarks AND b) pagelabels (custom page numbering) need to be retained.

Retaining bookmarks when merging happens by default with PyPDF2 and pdftk, but not with pdfrw.
Pagelabels are consistently not retained in PyPDF2, pdftk or pdfrw.

I am guessing, after having searched a lot, that there is no straightforward approach to doing what I want. If I'm wrong then I hope someone can point to this easy solution. But, if there is no easy solution, any tips on how to get this going in python will be much appreciated!

Some example code:

1) With PyPDF2

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader 
tmp1 = PdfFileReader('file1.pdf', 'rb')
tmp2 = PdfFileReader('file2.pdf', 'rb')
#extracting pagelabels is easy
pl1 = tmp1.trailer['/Root']['/PageLabels']
pl2 = tmp2.trailer['/Root']['/PageLabels']
#but PdfFileWriter or PdfFileMerger does not support writing from what I understand
```

So I dont know how to proceed from here

2) With pdfrw (has more promise)

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter
writer = PdfWriter()
#read 1st file
tmp1 = PdfReader('file1')
#add the pages
writer.addpages(tmp1.pages)
#copy bookmarks to writer
writer.trailer.Root.Outlines = tmp1.Root.Outlines
#copy pagelabels to writer
writer.trailer.Root.PageLabels = tmp1.Root.PageLabels
#read second file
tmp2 = PdfReader('file2')
#append pages
writer.addpages(tmp2.pages)
# so far so good
```

Page numbers of bookmarks from 2nd file need to be offset before adding them, but when reading outlines I almost always get (IndirectObject, XXX) instead of page numbers. Its unclear how to get page numbers for each label and bookmark using pdfrw. So, I'm stuck again

zp

Comment: Been wanting a solution for this! Some clues in this query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794994/python-pypdf4-how-do-i-specify-the-pagelabels-in-the-created-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the existing `PageLabels` and add them to the merged output, taking care to add an offset to the page index entry, based on the number of pages already added.

This solution also requires `PyPDF4`, since `PyPDF2` produces a weird error (see bottom).

```py
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader 

# To manipulate the PDF dictionary
import PyPDF4.pdf as PDF

import logging

def add_nums(num_entry, page_offset, nums_array):
    for num in num_entry['/Nums']:
        if isinstance(num, (int)):
            logging.debug("Found page number %s, offset %s: ", num, page_offset)

            # Add the physical page information
            nums_array.append(PDF.NumberObject(num+page_offset))
        else:
            # {'/S': '/r'}, or {'/S': '/D', '/St': 489}
            keys = num.keys()
            logging.debug("Found page label, keys: %s", keys)
            number_type = PDF.DictionaryObject()
            # Always copy the /S entry
            s_entry = num['/S']
            number_type.update({PDF.NameObject("/S"): PDF.NameObject(s_entry)})
            logging.debug("Adding /S entry: %s", s_entry)

            if '/St' in keys:
                # If there is an /St entry, fetch it
                pdf_label_offset = num['/St']
                # and add the new offset to it
                logging.debug("Found /St %s", pdf_label_offset)
                number_type.update({PDF.NameObject("/St"): PDF.NumberObject(pdf_label_offset)})

            # Add the label information
            nums_array.append(number_type)

    return nums_array

def write_merged(pdf_readers):
    # Output
    merger = PdfFileMerger()

    # For PageLabels information
    page_labels = []
    page_offset = 0
    nums_array = PDF.ArrayObject()

    # Iterate through all the inputs
    for pdf_reader in pdf_readers:
        try:
            # Merge the content
            merger.append(pdf_reader)

            # Handle the PageLabels
            # Fetch page information
            old_page_labels = pdf_reader.trailer['/Root']['/PageLabels']
            page_count = pdf_reader.getNumPages()

            # Add PageLabel information
            add_nums(old_page_labels, page_offset, nums_array)
            page_offset = page_offset + page_count

        except Exception as err:
            print("ERROR: %s" % err)

    # Add PageLabels
    page_numbers = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    page_numbers.update({PDF.NameObject("/Nums"): nums_array})

    page_labels = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    page_labels.update({PDF.NameObject("/PageLabels"): page_numbers})

    root_obj = merger.output._root_object
    root_obj.update(page_labels)

    # Write output
    merger.write('merged.pdf')


pdf_readers = []
tmp1 = PdfFileReader('file1.pdf', 'rb')
tmp2 = PdfFileReader('file2.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_readers.append(tmp1)
pdf_readers.append(tmp2)

write_merged(pdf_readers)
```

Note: PyPDF2 produces this weird error:

```py
  ...
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 552, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    data[key] = value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 507, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError("key must be PdfObject")
ValueError: key must be PdfObject
```

Comment: Thanks KevinM. All these days I was struggling because I did not know how to access the root object of `PdfFileMerger()` class. After reading the answer to your own question, I 'solved' my problem by using `PdfFileMerger()` to retain bookmarks and `PdfFileWriter()` to add bookmarks! Now that I know `.output._root_object` is available to access root, I retained bookmarks in a manner very similar to your suggestion. It works for me using PyPDF2 though. So, I making my script available just in case...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, I'm posting a generic solution to merge several pdfs that works in PyPDF2. Dont know what is different to make this work in PyPDF2 other than initializing pls as `ArrayObject()`

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
import PyPDF2.pdf as PDF

# pls holds all the pagelabels as we iterate through multiple pdfs
pls = PDF.ArrayObject()
# used to offset bookmarks 
pageCount = 0
cpdf = PdfFileMerger()
# pdffiles is a list of all files to be merged
for i in range(len(pdffiles)):
    tmppdf = PdfFileReader(pdffiles[i], 'rb')
    cpdf.append(tmppdf)
    # copy all the pagelabels which I assume is present in all files
    # you could use 'try' in case no pagelabels are present
    plstmp = tmppdf.trailer['/Root']['/PageLabels']['/Nums']
    # sometimes keys are indirect objects
    # so, iterate through each pagelabel and...
    for j in range(len(plstmp)):
        # ... get the actual values 
        plstmp[j] = plstmp[j].getObject()
        # offset pagenumbers by current count of pages
        if isinstance(plstmp[j], int): 
            plstmp[j] = PDF.NumberObject(plstmp[j] + pageCount) 
    # once all the pagelabels are processed I append to pls
    pls += plstmp
    #increment pageCount
    pageCount += tmppdf.getNumPages()

# rest follows KevinM's answer
pagenums = PDF.DictionaryObject()
pagenums.update({PDF.NameObject('/Nums') : pls})
pagelabels = PDF.DictionaryObject()
pagelabels.update({PDF.NameObject('/PageLabels') : pagenums})
cpdf.output._root_object.update(pagelabels)
cpdf.write("filename.pdf")
```

Comment: this is giving me "KeyError: '/PageLabels'"

Comment: Is it perhaps because there are no page labels in the pdf? Sorry for the really late reponse.

Comment: Would you mind making a 2023 update? PyPDF2 is deprecated and moved into pypdf. `PdfFileMerger` became `PdfMerger`. `reader.getNumPages` is just `len(reader.pages)`, ...