# Python/PyPDF4: How do I specify the /PageLabels in the created PDF?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation, pypdf

I am using PyPDF4 to create an [offline-readable version](https://gitlab.com/kev-m/nature-journal-downloader) of the journal "Nature".

I use PyPDF4 PdfFileReader to read the individual article PDFs and PdfFileWriter to create a single, merged ouput.

The problem that I am trying to solve is that the page numbers of some issues do not start at 1, for example, [issue 7805](https://www.nature.com/nature/volumes/580/issues/7805) starts with page 563.

How do I specify the desired `/PageLabels` in the document catalog?

```py
    for pdf_file in pdf_files:
        input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_file, 'rb'))
        page_indices = file_page_dictionary[pdf_file]
        for page_index in page_indices:
            page = input_pdf.getPage(page_index)

            # Specify actual page number here:
            # page.setPageNumber(actual_page_numbers[page_index])

            output.addPage(page)

    with open(pdf_output_name, 'wb') as f:
        output.write(f)
```

Comment: Use [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) instead of PyPDF2/PyPDF3/PyPDF4. I am the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. We improved pypdf a lot in 2022.

Comment: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfWriter.html#pypdf.PdfWriter.set_page_label

Comment: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#pypdf.PdfReader.page_labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exploring the PDF standard and a bit of hacking, I found that the following function will add a single `PageLabels` entry that creates page lables starting from offset (i.e. the first page will be labelled the offset, the second page, offset+1, etc.).

```py
# output_pdf is an instance of PdfFileWriter().
# offset is the desired page offset.
def add_pagelabels(output_pdf, offset):
    number_type = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    number_type.update({PDF.NameObject("/S"):PDF.NameObject("/D")})
    number_type.update({PDF.NameObject("/St"):PDF.NumberObject(offset)})

    nums_array = PDF.ArrayObject()
    nums_array.append(PDF.NumberObject(0)) # physical page index
    nums_array.append(number_type)

    page_numbers = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    page_numbers.update({PDF.NameObject("/Nums"):nums_array})

    page_labels = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    page_labels.update({PDF.NameObject("/PageLabels"): page_numbers})

    root_obj = output_pdf._root_object
    root_obj.update(page_labels)
```

Additional page label entries can be created (i.e. with different offsets or different numbering styles).

Note that the first PDF page has an index of 0.

```py
# Use PyPDF to manipulate pages
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader 

# To manipulate the PDF dictionary
import PyPDF4.pdf as PDF

def pdf_pagelabels_roman():
    number_type = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    number_type.update({PDF.NameObject("/S"):PDF.NameObject("/r")})
    return number_type

def pdf_pagelabels_decimal():
    number_type = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    number_type.update({PDF.NameObject("/S"):PDF.NameObject("/D")})
    return number_type

def pdf_pagelabels_decimal_with_offset(offset):
    number_type = pdf_pagelabels_decimal()
    number_type.update({PDF.NameObject("/St"):PDF.NumberObject(offset)})
    return number_type

...
    nums_array = PDF.ArrayObject()
    # Each entry consists of an index followed by a page label...
    nums_array.append(PDF.NumberObject(0))  # Page 0:
    nums_array.append(pdf_pagelabels_roman()) # Roman numerals

    # Each entry consists of an index followed by a page label...
    nums_array.append(PDF.NumberObject(1)) # Page 1 -- 10:
    nums_array.append(pdf_pagelabels_decimal_with_offset(first_offset)) # Decimal numbers, with Offset

    # Each entry consists of an index followed by a page label...
    nums_array.append(PDF.NumberObject(10)) # Page 11 --> :
    nums_array.append(pdf_pagelabels_decimal_with_offset(second_offset))


    page_numbers = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    page_numbers.update({PDF.NameObject("/Nums"):nums_array})

    page_labels = PDF.DictionaryObject()
    page_labels.update({PDF.NameObject("/PageLabels"): page_numbers})

    root_obj = output._root_object
    root_obj.update(page_labels)
```

Comment: I have been looking for something like this. When I use your code though, I'm unable to write the pdf in the final step. What was the code you used to actually write the file? I get the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'writeToStream'`

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is different: retain bookmarks and pagelabels when combining several documents. Query here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740267/merging-pdfs-while-retaining-custom-page-numbers-aka-pagelabels-and-bookmarks

Comment: It looks like you are using a naked number. All numbers in the PageLabels structure must be wrapped with `PDF.NumberObject( xxx )`.

Comment: I posted an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740267/merging-pdfs-while-retaining-custom-page-numbers-aka-pagelabels-and-bookmarks/61954278#61954278