# How to extract proper page number of a pdf using python

Tags: python, regex, pypdf

The code extracts the page number that is mentioned below every page, but I need the actual page number which is the file page number, not the document page number. I have also attached the screenshot and marked the page number in red that needs to be extracted. Please look into it.
[image: marked page number in red needs to be extracted]

Here is the code I have tried.

```
import PyPDF2
import re

obj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(r"avnet_202209 (1).pdf")

pgno = obj.getNumPages()

S = "Basis of presentation and new accounting pronouncements"

for i in range(0, pgno):
    PgOb = obj.getPage(i)
    Text = PgOb.extractText()
    if re.search(S,Text):
         print("String Found on Page: " + str(i))
```

The output was :
String Found on Page: 7
String Found on Page: 22

Required output:
String Found on Page: 8
String Found on Page: 23
​

Comment: Isn't the actual file pagenumber just `i + 1`..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve Custom page labels from document with pyPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360999/retrieve-custom-page-labels-from-document-with-pypdf)

Comment: @AKX But how does the code identify itself that doc page number (mentioned at below) start from a specific page

Comment: @Ron Not exactly. Those codes shows total number of pages in the pdf

Comment: I would say that the document would always start at page `1`. Do you have any examples that show otherwise ??

Answer (score 2):

There are three things you could mean.

I assume you install [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/). I became the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. We only continue development of `pypdf` and `pypdf` already has all of the features of `PyPDF2`.

**1. Page Index**

That is what you start with. If you iterate over the pages, you just need to save the index:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
for index, page in enumerate(reader.pages)
    ...
```

For example, when I want to print something I need to enter (index+1).

### 2. Total page count

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
print(f"The PDF document has {len(reader.pages)} pages in total")
```

### 3. Page label

For example, [this file](https://github.com/MartinThoma/GeoTopo/raw/master/GeoTopo.pdf) has the first few pages being labeled as `i`, `ii`, ...

Those are called "page labels".

I've recently added a PR to [add support in pypdf](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/pull/1519)

I will make a release latest on Sunday (01.01.2023). You can then do this:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
for index, page in enumerate(reader.pages)
    print(f"index={index}: label={reader.page_labels[index]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems that the PyPDF label option doesnt work. Please find this alternative code here.

```
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

def extract_page_numbers(pdf_path):
    # Open the PDF file
    pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)

    # Iterate through each page
    for page_number in range(pdf_document.page_count):
        # Get the page
        page = pdf_document[page_number]

        # Get the text in the bottom region of the page
        rect = page.rect  # Full page rectangle
        bottom_rect = fitz.Rect(rect.x0, rect.y1 - 30, rect.x1, rect.y1)  # Bottom 30 units rectangle
        text = page.get_text("text", clip=bottom_rect)

        # Extract the page number from the text
        page_number_str = text.strip()

        # Print the result
        print(f"Page {page_number + 1}: {page_number_str}")

    # Close the PDF document
    pdf_document.close()
```

Have a nice Day!